# How OAuth2ClientContext persists access token

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

OAuth2RestTemplate uses OAuth2ClientContext for saving the access token. But I am unable to understand how OAuth2ClientContext is persisting access tokens between subsequent request.

NOTE:- I am using client_credential grant type and my application is stateless.

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth2ClientContext-Bean is instanciated in scope "Session", so it is individual for each user-session.

See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-session